# Linux mint screen not showing correctly with nvidia gpu

Tags: linux, nvidia, kde-plasma, linux-mint

I downloaded Linux mint KDE 16 64 bit iso.

but when i boot with it, after 10 sec screen blink continuously i cant even see anything on the desktop except few Linux on Linux mint default wallpaper.

I am getting too much irritated and disappointed from Linux pls help.

I have Amd athlon x2 process with inbuilt nvidia 7025 graphics.

Having 4 GB DDR2 ram of Kingston.

any help pls ?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO; belongs on [su]

Comment: i don't know what is off topic here sir, i just ask a question on linux which is general topic here

Comment: StackOverflow is for _programming_ questions.  Your question is on-topic for [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nikhil, i can know your pain. lets follow some steps, see if they work.

At your desktop just **navigate your mouse on the desktop bottom left corner**, keep navigating you will get some content there.

- click on **start menu launcher**
- search for **system settings.**
- click on **Desktop effect** in the second line first option.
- Go to **Advance**
- in composting type **switch to OPENGL 1.2** (Default was OPENGL 2.0).

click on apply on the bottom left and then everything is fine now you can proceed further.

you should install your graphic driver for permanent solution

**System setting >> Driver manager >> click on your nvidia card and then Apply changes.**

And one more thing Linux isn't irritating ;)

Comment: Thanks !! a lot man, you saved my day ... i was thinking that my screen was faulty.. thank you

Real people here, who give time to newbies,, great bro

Comment: enjoy KDE and answer markup is appreciable